# How to set value in ArrayList inside ArrayList?

Tags: android, json, arraylist

I have JSON like this,

```
{
  "resultFlag": true,
  "successMessage": "Data Received",
  "category": [
    {
      "CategoryID": "4",
      "CategoryTitle": "YSafety",
      "CategoryImage": "",
      "Percentage": "25%",
      "Level": 16,
      "Days": 60,
      "Topic": [
        {
          "TopicID": "11",
          "TopicTitle": "Safety during Online transactions",
          "TopicImage": ""
        },
        {
          "TopicID": "12",
          "TopicTitle": "Anti-Theft mobile Features",
          "TopicImage": ""
        },
        {
          "TopicID": "32",
          "TopicTitle": "Magic of Science",
          "TopicImage": ""
        }
      ],
      "Sponsor": [
        {
          "SponsorID": 1,
          "SponsorName": "adidas",
          "SponsorImage": "http://assets/upload/SPONSOR/adidas.jpg"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "CategoryID": "5",
      "CategoryTitle": "YSoccer",
      "CategoryImage": "",
      "Percentage": "25%",
      "Level": 16,
      "Days": 60,
      "Topic": [
        {
          "TopicID": "13",
          "TopicTitle": "Others",
          "TopicImage": ""
        },
        {
          "TopicID": "14",
          "TopicTitle": "Rules",
          "TopicImage": ""
        },
        {
          "TopicID": "33",
          "TopicTitle": "Magic of Nature",
          "TopicImage": ""
        }
      ],
      "Sponsor": [
        {
          "SponsorID": 1,
          "SponsorName": "adidas",
          "SponsorImage": "http://assets/upload/SPONSOR/adidas.jpg"
        }
      ]
    } ]
}
```

my code is to fetch array inside array is below,

```
static ArrayList<String> al_sponsor_image = new ArrayList<String>();

    static ArrayList<ArrayList<String>> al_al_topic_id = new ArrayList<ArrayList<String>>();

    if (resultFlag == true) {
                            String success = response.getString("successMessage");

                            JSONArray array_category = response.getJSONArray("category");

                            for (int i = 0; i < array_category.length(); i++) {

                                JSONObject obj_category = array_category.getJSONObject(i);

                                String category_id = obj_category.getString("CategoryID");
                                String category_title = obj_category.getString("CategoryTitle");
                                String category_image = obj_category.getString("CategoryImage");
                                String percentage = obj_category.getString("Percentage");
                                String level = obj_category.getString("Level");
                                String days = obj_category.getString("Days");

                                //  al_category_id.add(category_id);
                                al_category_title.add(category_title);
                                //  al_category_image.add(category_image);
                                al_percentage.add(percentage);
                                al_level.add(level);
                                al_days.add(days);

                                JSONArray array_topic = obj_category.getJSONArray("Topic");

                                JSONArray array_sponsor = obj_category.getJSONArray("Sponsor");

                                al_topic_id.clear();
                                al_topic_title.clear();
                                al_topic_image.clear();

                                al_sponsor_id.clear();
                                al_sponsor_name.clear();
                                al_sponsor_image.clear();

                                for (int j = 0; j < array_topic.length(); j++) {

                                    JSONObject obj_topic = array_topic.getJSONObject(j);

                                    String topic_id = obj_topic.getString("TopicID");
                                    String topic_title = obj_topic.getString("TopicTitle");
                                    String topic_image = obj_topic.getString("TopicImage");

                                    al_topic_id.add(topic_id);
                                    al_topic_title.add(topic_title);
                                    al_topic_image.add(topic_image);

                                   /* String[] st_sub_array_topic_title = al_topic_title.toArray(new String[al_topic_title.size()]);
                                    String[] st_sub_array_topic_image = al_topic_image.toArray(new String[al_topic_image.size()]);

                                    st_array_topic_title = new String[i][];
                                    st_array_topic_title[j] = st_sub_array_topic_title;

                                    int[] itemImageList = new int[j];
                                    itemImageList[j] = R.drawable.dummy_flower;
                                    st_array_topic_image[j] = itemImageList;*/

                                    /*{itemImageList, itemImageList, itemImageList, itemImageList, itemImageList, itemImageList, itemImageList, itemImageList};*/
                                    /*{R.drawable.dummy_flower, R.drawable.dummy_flower, R.drawable.dummy_flower, R.drawable.dummy_flower, R.drawable.dummy_flower, R.drawable.dummy_flower, R.drawable.dummy_flower, R.drawable.dummy_flower, R.drawable.dummy_flower, R.drawable.dummy_flower};*/

                                    //  st_array_topic_image = new String[i][];
                                    //  st_array_topic_image[j] = st_sub_array_topic_image;

                                }

                                al_al_topic_id.add(i, al_topic_id);
                                al_al_topic_title.add(i, al_topic_title);
                                al_al_topic_image.add(i, al_topic_image);

                                System.out.println("al_al_topic_id : " + al_al_topic_id);
                                System.out.println("al_al_topic_title : " + al_al_topic_title);
                                System.out.println("al_al_topic_image : " + al_al_topic_image);

                                //     String[][] st_array_topic_image

                                for (int j = 0; j < array_sponsor.length(); j++) {

                                    JSONObject obj_sponsor = array_sponsor.getJSONObject(j);

                                    String sponsor_id = obj_sponsor.getString("SponsorID");
                                    String sponsor_name = obj_sponsor.getString("SponsorName");
                                    String sponsor_image = obj_sponsor.getString("SponsorImage");

                                    al_sponsor_id.add(sponsor_id);
                                    al_sponsor_name.add(sponsor_name);
                                    al_sponsor_image.add(sponsor_image);

                                    /*String[] st_sub_array_sponsor_name = al_sponsor_name.toArray(new String[al_sponsor_name.size()]);
                                    String[] st_sub_array_sponsor_image = al_sponsor_image.toArray(new String[al_sponsor_image.size()]);

                                    st_array_sponsor_name = new String[i][];
                                    st_array_sponsor_name[j] = st_sub_array_sponsor_name;

                                    st_array_sponsor_image = new String[i][];
                                    st_array_sponsor_image[j] = st_sub_array_sponsor_image;*/

                                }

                                al_al_sponsor_id.add(i, al_sponsor_id);
                                al_al_sponsor_name.add(i, al_sponsor_name);
                                al_al_sponsor_image.add(i, al_sponsor_image);

                                System.out.println("al_al_sponsor_id : " + al_al_sponsor_id);
                                System.out.println("al_al_sponsor_name : " + al_al_sponsor_name);
                                System.out.println("al_al_sponsor_image : " + al_al_sponsor_image);

                            }

                         /* String[] st_array_category_title = al_category_title.toArray(new String[al_category_title.size()]);
                            String[] st_array_percentage = al_percentage.toArray(new String[al_percentage.size()]);
                            String[] st_array_level = al_level.toArray(new String[al_level.size()]);
                            String[] st_array_days = al_days.toArray(new String[al_days.size()]); */

                            rv_learning_cards.setAdapter(new AdapterLearningCards(activity, al_category_title, al_percentage, al_level, al_days, al_al_topic_image, al_al_topic_title, al_al_sponsor_image));

                        }
```

When I print the al_al_topic_title, it replaces all array with lat array...

```
al_al_topic_title : [[Travel and Activity Gear, Types of Activities], [Travel and Activity Gear, Types of Activities], [Travel and Activity Gear, Types of Activities], [Travel and Activity Gear, Types of Activities], [Travel and Activity Gear, Types of Activities], [Travel and Activity Gear, Types of Activities], [Travel and Activity Gear, Types of Activities], [Travel and Activity Gear, Types of Activities], [Travel and Activity Gear, Types of Activities]]

al_al_topic_title : [[Others, Others], [Others, Others], [Others, Others], [Others, Others], [Others, Others], [Others, Others], [Others, Others], [Others, Others], [Others, Others], [Others, Others]]
```

Can anyone give me suggetion?

Comment: why make this complicated with an ArrayList<ArrayList<String>> ?? Why didn't you use classes for the same? what is mean is ArrayList<YourClassNameWithVariables>.... this would be a better approach

Answer (score 0):

Your basic approach to solve problem is wrong,you can easily do this with bean class Category.java which is having

```
public class Category
{
   String CategoryID;
   String CategoryTitle;
   String CategoryImage;
   String Percentage;
   String Level;
   String Days;
   ArrayList<Topic> topic;

   .......
   Getter and setter methods here
   .........
}

class Topic
{
    String TopicID;
    String TopicTitle;
    String TopicImage;
     .......
   Getter and setter methods here
   .........

 }
```

Now add parsed data to `ArrayList<Category> category`. Then above issue will not come also code will more clear to understand by other developers.

Comment: I have also tried with this, it is also replacing last element at all position

Answer (score 0):

your code is potentially buggy and you can find whatever you want in your json in this way:

**1**

Go to http://www.jsonschema2pojo.org/ site and paste your json
(this site generate java classes for your json (Pojo))

**2**

Copy java files to your project

**3**

You should use serialization/deserialization library for converting your json string to java object
i recommend you Gson

**4**

After importing Gson to your project write this code

```
   Gson gson = new Gson();
   YOUR_GENERETED CLASS response = gson.fromJson(YOUR_JSON_STRING ,YOUR_GENERETED CLASS.class);
```

and Finally you can fetch what ever you want from response object

Comment: This is essentially a link-only answer, because if the link under bullet 1 dies this answer is useless. Please revise this answer to one not using off-site resources, as link-only answers can get deleted.

Answer (score 0):

Use Gson to parse your JSON response instead of parsing it manually. It will reduce lot of problem.

Gson is an open source library to serialize and deserialize java object to (and from) JSON.

You need to create plain java object classes for your JSON response as shown below.

CategoryJsonResponse.java

```
class CategoryJsonResponse {
boolean resultFlag;
String successMessage;
ArrayList<Category> category;}
```

Category.java

```
class Category {
int CategoryID;
String CategoryTitle;
String CategoryImage;
String Percentage;
int Level;
int Days;
ArrayList<Topic> Topic;
ArrayList<Sponsor> Sponsor;}
```

Sponser.java

```
class Sponsor {
int SponsorID;
String SponsorName;
String SponsorImage;}
```

Topic.java

```
class Topic {
int TopicID;
String TopicTitle;
String TopicImage;}
```

Now you need to write below few line of codes to parse your JSON response. I am assuming we are getting JSON response in "response" variable.

```
GsonBuilder gsonBuilder = new GsonBuilder();
Gson gson = gsonBuilder.create();

CategoryJsonResponse categoryJsonResponse = gson.fromJson(response.toString(), CategoryJsonResponse .class);
```

Now you have entire JSON response inside categoryJsonResponse object and you can read any value in normal java way. And last point. To add GSON in your project, you just need to add below dependency in your app level gradle file.

```
compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.2.4'
```